# How do I display multiple entity type fields into a single form?

Tags: forms

How do I display multiple entity type fields into a single form?

I have retrieved multiple entity type fields using the following code.

```
$entity =\Drupal::entityTypeManager()
->getStorage('node')
->loadByProperties([
    'type' => ['page', 'article'],
  ]);
```

I want to convert this into a form with edit options. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
\Drupal::service('entity.form_builder')->getForm($entity, 'form');
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: EntityForms can only manage a single entity type. You'll need to create a custom form and pass it the two entities if you want the form to manage more than one entity type.

Comment: Okay, thank you.